# tailwind default background colors doesn't work in a new project

Tags: tailwind-css

I've installed tailwind in a new project and seems work fine. When I try to apply a background black color to the body it works:

```
<body class="bg-black">
```

But when I try to apply another default color it doesn't work:

```
<body class="bg-slate-500">
```

Why? How can I add the default color palete to bg utility classes?

```
//tailwind.config.js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ],
}
```

Tailwind 3.1.4
[Here is the project repo](https://github.com/aitormendez/testingReact/blob/main/package.json#L41)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to either define a colors object that pick which color palettes you want/need or simply import the default colors in your `tailwind.config.js`.

```
config.colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-the-default-colors

## Update 2

As asked, I'm including a full example of where to include the imported colors in the Tailwind CSS config file.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ],
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me how to include this config in the context of my tailwind.config.js file? (I've included it in the question) https://github.com/aitormendez/testingReact/blob/main/tailwind.config.js Thanks!

Comment: I updated the original answer with a full config file example

Comment: Sorry! I have an error "config is not defined"

Comment: Apologies, I fixed the issue, it needs to be a new variable. I updated the code to use `const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')`

Answer (score 0):

try using `className` instead of `class`

Comment: It is not a jsx file. Is an HTML file: https://github.com/aitormendez/testingReact/blob/main/public/index.html#L29

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of deprecated warnings, you may manually remove deprecated colors:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')

delete colors['lightBlue'];
delete colors['warmGray'];
delete colors['trueGray'];
delete colors['coolGray'];
delete colors['blueGray'];

module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}'],
  darkMode: 'media',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```